# Mysql PHP - Sort table after inserting row

Tags: php, mysql

How can I have my table sort after a row has been inserted?

I tried the following code but am getting an error:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO vendors (vendor, pavcode, pavname) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ORDER 
BY vendor ASC";
```

Thanks for any help.

Edit: I am getting a syntax error as follows:

> ERROR: Could not prepare query: INSERT INTO vendors (vendor, pavcode, pavname) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ORDER BY (vendor) ASC. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY (vendor) ASC' at line 1

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use temporary ordering when using a `SELECT`.

```
SELECT *
FROM vendors
ORDER BY vendor ASC
```

You can also `ALTER` the order permanently using:

```
ALTER TABLE vendor ORDER BY vendor
```

You would need to run the `ALTER` after your insert to re-assert the permanent ordering, as it is not preserved after row changes. It may be more efficient to use an index, along with the `SELECT` ordering, rather than constantly re-ordering the table.